# Change Bootstrap CSS for a button property after click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap and I'm trying to change the color of the button but it turns out that after the button has been clicked and mouse is not on it, the color is changed to blue again.

That is the color I chose:

[image]

But after a click and if the mouse is not 'inside', the color goes to blue:

[image]

I've already changed the most properties as you can see below:

```
.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #EB984E;
  border-color: #EB984E;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #EB984E;
  border-color: #EB984E;
}

.btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
}

.btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary:disabled {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: ##EB984E;
  border-color: ##EB984E;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: ##EB984E;
  border-color: ##EB984E;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
}

.buttons input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

What is missing to the entire button gets this orange color (#EB984E)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is the `:focus` pseudo element and `focus` class, i.e.

```
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus, {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #EB984E;
  border-color: #EB984E;
}
```

FYI, you have a few mistakes in your CSS: you are using `##EB984E` (i.e. double `#`) in some rules instead of `#EB984E`.

Also FYI a few notes on how to style buttons for **usability** and **accessibility**:

- you are using the **same colour for hover** - this should be a different colour to indicate that the button is active and ready to be clicked.
- You also use the **same colour for the focus outline** - this outline is used to show which button has focus when the site is being used with a keyboard. It is usually a different colour to highlight this, although as long as it's clear which has focus its ok.

**Now, your code working the way you want** (but I highly recommend you consider the above points for your live site) :)

```css
.buttoncontainer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  .btn:focus,
  .btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EB984E;
    border-color: #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary:focus,
  .btn-primary.focus,
  .btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EB984E;
    border-color: #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary:focus,
  .btn-primary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary.disabled,
  .btn-primary:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EB984E;
    border-color: #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
  .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EB984E;
    border-color: #EB984E;
  }
  
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
  .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #EB984E;
  }
  
  .buttons input:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">One </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Two</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Three</button>
</div>
```

(Also FYI - the CSS is not included in the CSS panel of the snippet because it gets overridden by the Bootstrap include.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. The problem still persists (blue color after click) but maybe it's because I'm using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">`. Should I use the CSS code all printed in the page exactly as you did?

Comment: @FelipeDourado No, you don't need to include the CSS in the page, but just make sure that you include your stylesheet link *after* the Bootstrap one - otherwise the Bootstrap CSS will override yours. But I think the problem might be the `##` in your background colours - there should only be one `#`. If you don't fix those, the button will turn blue when you click it. They are in a few places so make sure you fixed them all!

Comment: Last question: do you know some good site to customize the colors of the button? I mean: I have no idea what colors match with each others considering hover and focus outline, so it'd be great to test until I discover a good one. It'd be even great if the site give me all the CSS code!

Comment: @FelipeDourado I don't know any for button colors because that usually depends on the website color scheme, I'm afraid! It's common to use a darker or lighter version of the same colour on hover. The border color for focus tends to be a pale colour, e.g. in Bootstrap the blue button has a pale blue border. Your focus CSS is ok - it is obvious which button has focus. This page might be interesting [CSS Button Styles](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/css-button) and here are [lots of CodePens for buttons](https://codepen.io/topic/buttons/picks) (but they might not work with Bootstrap). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background-color and border-color as orange for your button with focus class, from your code above, you only set box-shadow as orange

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `:hover` and change the properties. When you move the mouse inside the button the new properties will be used and when you move the mouse out of the button it will turn back to a normal color.

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #EB984E;
  border-color: #EB984E;
  padding:10px 20px;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary">One</button>
```

Comment: Your contribution is welcome, but this answer does not address the problem in the question. The button works on hover, the problem is when it is clicked. You code doesn't seem to do anything different to the code in the question except change the colours to red, white and blue on hover.